# Automatically enable custom inspection from IntelliJ Plugin

Tags: intellij-plugin

I've created an IntelliJ plugin with some custom inspections. After going into Settings and enabling all of the inspections manually, they're working fine, but I'd like the inspections to be enabled automatically.

Is there any way of doing this, short of manually reaching into the `inspectionProfiles`s XML and inserting the additional `inspection_tool` lines? I'd obviously prefer to avoid tweaking config files that may change in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **enabledByDefault** attribute in **localInspection** (or **globalInspection**) tag of plugin.xml file.
If set to true the inspection will be enabled automatically.

Comment: I see - what's the difference between using `inspectionToolProvider` vs adding `localInspection` tags?

Comment: I don't know. Seems like different approaches to the same thing. I use localInspection tags in XML.

Comment: Yeah, `localInspection` seems to be the way to go - thanks.